# Laravel Eloquent ORM Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, relational-database

This should be *really* simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

There are two tables:

```
`images`
|-  `id`
|-  `path`
|-  `name`

`foods`
|-  `id`
|-  `image_id`
```

And two models:

```
class Image extends Eloquent {

    public function food() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Food');
    }

}

class Food extends Eloquent {

    public function image() {
        return $this->hasOne('Image');
    }

}
```

The idea is that each `food` has a single `image` associated with it through the `image_id` column in its `foods` table row.  A single `image` can be associated to multiple foods.

I'd like to be able to do something like this in a controller:

```
$food = Food::with('image')->find(1);
```

...but, of course, I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'images.food_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `images` where `images`.`food_id` in (1))

...because Eloquent would like each `image` to have a `food_id`.  But, of course, `image`s don't have `food_id`s.  Foods have `image_id`s.

Please help a frustrated coder out.  :)

Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**

Thank you so much, duellsy.

I have updated my models to this:

```
class Image extends Eloquent {

    public function food() {
        return $this->hasMany('Food');
    }

}

class Food extends Eloquent {

    public function image() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Image');
    }

}
```

...and now the `Food::with('image')` call works.

I truly don't understand why 'Food' belongs to 'Image' though...  perhaps someone might be able to explain why the syntax doesn't match the grammer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it grammatically sounds like it should be a `hasOne` relationship, the way your data is setup is actually a `belongsTo` relationship.

i.e., the food table has the foreign key, so it `belongs to` whatever that foreign key is pointing to

Additionally, the inverse is true for the images model, it doesn't `belong to` anything since there's no foreign key or pivot tables involved. Instead, it `has many` foods

#### What's with the backwards sytax?

The grammar / syntax seems a bit backwards in your case purely because in most systems you would expect that a food item has many images, not the other way around. It can get tricky often, which is why it's always worth forgetting about the model names and just thinking about who has the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks so much, man.  Worked perfectly.  I really don't understand why the syntax wouldn't match the grammar?  But, I'm just glad it works.

Comment: Cool. In most cases, it does, it's just that the way your data is structured is a bit different to normal. In most other systems, you would expect a food would have multiple images.

Comment: If a food did have multiple images... I'd have to have a 3rd table, right?  Let's say `foods_images`.  And then, would I also need a `FoodImage` model to tie everything together?

Comment: if the food had multiple images, but the image also belonged to multiple foods, then yes, you would need a pivot table.

Comment: I see, it makes sense now.  Thanks again, you rock!  :)